# Symfony - JOIN made with a varchar field that has multiple values (or ENUM)

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

I have a table like this:

[image: initial table design]

the idea is that based on the field "allowed_to_copy_id" I will allow items to be copied.

In the above example the items that are in category #1 can be copied ONLY in category 2 (relationship between "id" and "allowed_to_copy_id").

So, in ../Entity/Category.php I have this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="sourceRestore")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="allowed_to_copy_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $copyCategory;
```

Ok, everythins works perfect!

Here's my problem:

I need to allow a category to be copied to one or more categories... So my database must look something like this:

[image: modified table]

I'm lost at the part where I'm getting my copyCategory object... Logically, I have get + set functions, but I don't get it how to tell to my webapp that now I'm not having only 1 category object... :(

Any ideas?

THank you!

Comment: You need to convert this to a [Many-to-Many](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) relationship.

Comment: something like: 

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="sourceRestore")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="selected_service_copy_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

Comment: @prodigitalson add your answer please in order to mark it as approved...

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert this to a [Many-to-Many](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) relationship.